# snmpbulk is taking too much time to fetch data

Tags: linux, perl, snmp, net-snmp

I am using snmpbulk to get data of devices in network using multiple OID's. but for those OID's there are lots of sub OID's(more than 20,000 for each OID's). So it takes much time to fetch data. How can I implement this so it will take less time.

Answer (score 1):

1. First obvious step - poll devices in parallel.
2. Move poller closer to devices to reduce RTT latency for requests.
3. Experiment with the max-repetitions field in the GETBULK PDU - send request for many OIDs at once.
4. Send multiple OID requests to a device simultaneously (for
   example use multiple instances of poller to query subsets of OIDs).
   Beware that it can easily overload CPU on device.